# Pandas: apply date_range() to a group of rows that share a fixed date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file of WTA matches that are structured like this:

```
season,date,name,location,level,surface,draw,round,winner,loser,status
1987,1986-12-01,Argentine Open,Buenos Aires,C1,clay,56,R64,Maria Lindstrom,Patrizia Murgo,f
1987,1986-12-01,Argentine Open,Buenos Aires,C1,clay,56,R64,Gabriela Mosca,Pascale Etchemendy,f
1987,1986-12-01,Argentine Open,Buenos Aires,C1,clay,56,R64,Vicki Nelson,Xochitl Escobedo,f
...
1987,1986-12-01,Argentine Open,Buenos Aires,C1,clay,56,SF,Gabriela Sabatini,Lori Mcneil,f
1987,1986-12-01,Argentine Open,Buenos Aires,C1,clay,56,SF,Arantxa Sanchez Vicario,Mariana Perez Roldan,f
1987,1986-12-01,Argentine Open,Buenos Aires,C1,clay,56,F,Gabriela Sabatini,Arantxa Sanchez Vicario,f
...
2023,2023-10-16,Transylvania Open,Cluj-Napoca,WTA250,hard,32,R32,Eva Lys,Sorana Cirstea,f
2023,2023-10-16,Transylvania Open,Cluj-Napoca,WTA250,hard,32,R32,Jaqueline Cristian,Celine Naef,f
2023,2023-10-16,Transylvania Open,Cluj-Napoca,WTA250,hard,32,R32,Patricia Maria Tig,Martha Matoula,f
...
2023,2023-10-16,Transylvania Open,Cluj-Napoca,WTA250,hard,32,SF,Tamara Korpatsch,Eva Lys,f
2023,2023-10-16,Transylvania Open,Cluj-Napoca,WTA250,hard,32,SF,Elena-Gabriela Ruse,Rebeka Masarova,f
2023,2023-10-16,Transylvania Open,Cluj-Napoca,WTA250,hard,32,F,Tamara Korpatsch,Elena-Gabriela Ruse,f
```

After reading the contents into a DataFrame, I would like to transform the DataFrame in such a way that for each tournament, which are unique in the combination of `['date','name']`, the date is advanced by one day after the initial `round` is completed.

```
date,round
1986-12-01,R64
1986-12-02,R32
1986-12-03,R16
1986-12-04,QF
1986-12-05,SF
1986-12-06,F
```

The result should look like this:

```
season,date,name,location,level,surface,draw,round,winner,loser,status
1987,1986-12-01,Argentine Open,Buenos Aires,C1,clay,56,R64,Maria Lindstrom,Patrizia Murgo,f
1987,1986-12-01,Argentine Open,Buenos Aires,C1,clay,56,R64,Gabriela Mosca,Pascale Etchemendy,f
1987,1986-12-01,Argentine Open,Buenos Aires,C1,clay,56,R64,Vicki Nelson,Xochitl Escobedo,f
...
1987,1986-12-05,Argentine Open,Buenos Aires,C1,clay,56,SF,Gabriela Sabatini,Lori Mcneil,f
1987,1986-12-05,Argentine Open,Buenos Aires,C1,clay,56,SF,Arantxa Sanchez Vicario,Mariana Perez Roldan,f
1987,1986-12-06,Argentine Open,Buenos Aires,C1,clay,56,F,Gabriela Sabatini,Arantxa Sanchez Vicario,f
...
2023,2023-10-16,Transylvania Open,Cluj-Napoca,WTA250,hard,32,R32,Eva Lys,Sorana Cirstea,f
2023,2023-10-16,Transylvania Open,Cluj-Napoca,WTA250,hard,32,R32,Jaqueline Cristian,Celine Naef,f
2023,2023-10-16,Transylvania Open,Cluj-Napoca,WTA250,hard,32,R32,Patricia Maria Tig,Martha Matoula,f
...
2023,2023-10-19,Transylvania Open,Cluj-Napoca,WTA250,hard,32,SF,Tamara Korpatsch,Eva Lys,f
2023,2023-10-19,Transylvania Open,Cluj-Napoca,WTA250,hard,32,SF,Elena-Gabriela Ruse,Rebeka Masarova,f
2023,2023-10-20,Transylvania Open,Cluj-Napoca,WTA250,hard,32,F,Tamara Korpatsch,Elena-Gabriela Ruse,f
```

The `date_range()` function seems like a good fit, but as I'm new to Pandas, I don't see a straightforward way to use it. What is a good solution to this?

Comment: HI, could you show what the expected result should look like?

Comment: Please provide simple (few cols and rows) before and after data covering more than one date and more than one tournament.

Comment: Edited the question with before and after examples.

Comment: Your expected output seems to be wrong. The new dates of the tournament `Transylvania Open|2023-10-16` don't match your logic. Can you make a little effort and *double-check* it, please ? Also, does your input csv always guarantee to have the six rounds for each tournament ?